# accessing private inner class field using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am wondering how I can access a private field of a private inner class using reflection for my JUnit tests.

Here is an example of what I need:

```
public class A
{
    private Map<Integer, InnerClass> objectMap = new TreeMap<Integer, InnerClass>.descendingMap();

    private class InnerClass    
    {
        private int fieldOne
        private int fieldTwo
    }
}
```

In this example, I want to access the values of fieldOne and fieldTwo that are in the instance of A.

I have tried the following:

```
A instanceA = new A(); 

Field privateObjectMapField = A.class.getDeclaredField("objectMap");
privateObjectMapField.setAccessible(true);
NavigableMap<Integer, Class<?>> fieldValue =  (NavigableMap<Integer, Class<?>>) privateObjectMapField.get(instanceA);

// 5 is a key in the map so this should set declaredClass to an instance of InnerClass
Class<?> declaredClass = fieldValue.get(5).getClass();
Field fieldOne = declaredClass.getDeclaredField("fieldOne");
fieldOne.setAccessible(true);
Assert.assertEquals(100, fieldOne.getInt(declaredClass));
```

In this case it crashses at: `Class<?> declaredClass = fieldValue.get(5).getClass();`
with the error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.A$InnerClass cannot be cast to java.lang.Class`

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

I hope this example is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
NavigableMap<Integer, InnerClass> fieldValue = (NavigableMap<Integer, InnerClass>) privateObjectMapField.get(instanceA);
```

Comment: InnerClass is private though so my JUnit class can't see it

Comment: So maybe you have to change your class structure as InnerClass could not be tested / reached in this example.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

`objectMap` is a `Map<Integer, A.InnerClass>`, and you're treating it as if it's a `Map<Integer, Class<?>>`.

Try this, instead:

```
NavigableMap<Integer, ?> fieldValue = ...
```

---

**Detailed answer** (you should read and understand this if you want to understand generics)

fieldValue is declared as a `NavigableMap<Integer, Class<?>>`, which means that this:

```
fieldValue.get(5)
```

just translates to this:

```
((Class<?>) fieldValue.get(5))
```

This is because of how [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) works. Basically, `declaredClass` isn't *really* a `NavigableMap<Integer, Class<?>>`, it's just a `NavigableMap` (that's its "raw type"), to which the compiler can add type checks and automatic casting.

So, what happens if the object at key 5 isn't really a `Class`? When you try to cast it, you'll get a ClassCastException. That's what's happening for you, since the object at key 5 is an `A.InnerClass`, not a `Class`. It's fundamentally no different than:

```
Object o = new InnerClass();
Class<?> boom = (Class<?>) o; // ClassCastException
```

As to the fix, that depends on what you're actually trying to do. If it's just for testing, you may consider making `InnerClass` have default visibility (aka package-private) instead of private. You can also retrieve `objectMap` as a `Map<Integer, ?>` and then call `fieldValue.get(5).getClass()`. That will get the object at key `5`, which happens to be an `InnerClass` (but you don't need to specify it at compile time), and then call `Object.getClass()` on it to get its class.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I still have the problem though.

I have this:
`NavigableMap<Integer, ?> fieldValue =  (NavigableMap<Integer, ?>) privateObjectMapField.get(instanceA);

Class<?> declaredClass = fieldValue.get(5).getClass();
Field fieldOne = declaredClass.getDeclaredField("fieldOne");
fieldOne.setAccessible(true);
Assert.assertEquals(100, fieldOne.getInt(declaredClass));
`
This time it fails on the getInt:
`Can not set int field com.test.A$InnerClass.fieldOne to java.lang.Class`

Should declared class still be a Class<?> here?

Comment: Sounds like a new question -- it's very hard to read so much code smushed into a comment. But I would encourage you to try and pick apart each step and debug it on your own, armed with your new understanding of how generics work. :)